# Musical Chairs Cipher: Intermediate

Tags: cipher

*This question is a continuation of the first question: [Musical Chairs Cipher](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/questions/84770/musical-chairs-cipher).*

The basic rules:

> Six children -- Alice, Ben, Carl, Denise, Eddie, and Flo -- are playing a game of musical chairs in class. On each of the five chairs is written a seven letter word.
>
> The children start out in alphabetical order, and maintain that same order through the whole game. At the end of each round, each person sits in a chair, except for one, who is out.
>
> Then, each of the sitting children scribbles out the word on their chair, in its place writing the same word under a vigenere cipher, using their name as the key.
>
> One chair is then removed before resuming the game, which continues until there is only one person left. When removed, the word written on the chair is no longer changed. The final chair's word is still changed by the winner.

So Alice, Bob, Carl, Denise, Eddie, and Flo are going to play another round of musical chairs in class when they are approached by Greg, Hillary, and Ivan, all of them wanting to play as well.

Greg, Hillary, and Ivan are not nearly as well behaved as the rest of the children, so while the others stay in the same alphabetical order through the whole game, they instead are hopping, pushing, and running all around the circle, constantly changing their positions between rounds. Other than that, they follow all the same rules as the rest.

Their teacher, not wanting to leave anyone out of the game, brings in three more chairs and writes up some more words, but she doesn't check to make sure they are the same length as the others.

If the game began with the words:

> CHEDDAR
> FONTINA
> MUNSTER
> HAVARTI
> RICOTTA
> ASIAGO
> STILTON
> PROVOLONE

And ended with:

> UDPCGUU
> ZCDUGQT
> CZBPNZI
> ORWSYFM
> YQNZTKY
> CRUSHF
> BOZZRJU
> CQSBQKIPB

What order did the children get out, and who won?

NOTE: I will accept code-based answers, but I expect a bit more than brute force.

Comment: Questions should be self-contained, so people do not have the inconvenience of clicking back and forth from the other one, so you should copy and paste the list of rules.

Comment: @Duck I have edited in the rules, thanks for letting me know

Comment: The teacher apparently wasn't too careful about how to spell "provolone", either :-).

Comment: I assume the "!" in front of RVJAQJP is just a typo?

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan yeah, i didn't notice lol

Comment: The teacher apparently wasn't too careful about how to spell "provolone", either :-). – Gareth McCaughan♦ Also edit this.

Comment: @Duck fixed "provolone" and respective outcome

Comment: Are you absolutely certain there are no remaining errors? (E.g., were the final results here copied and pasted from computer output?) I ask because I thought I had a nice way to solve this but it's yielding no solutions; my approach is "fragile" so any error anywhere will kill it. Most likely the error is mine, but it would be good to know how certain you are that it isn't yours :-).

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan I checked my solutions, and apparently I encrypted one one too many times, and the other I misspelled the starting word. It's fixed now, and I used a computer to generate these.

Comment: Ok, so, here are my thoughts on this puzzle: the first one was a good puzzle, just barely solvable by hand, without having to resort to a boring computer search. This puzzle adds different word lengths, which doesn't affect anything at all, a more unpredictable order, which removes deduction possibilities, and more names, which adds exponentially more possibilities, ie. more boringness. While this one may be interesting as a programming exercise, the first one was better as a puzzle.

Comment: @Bass I was struggling to produce a harder version of the first that would not make it tedious to do by hand, and I thought that scrambling order was a good method, but didn't anticipate the number of possibilities that would result. I will try harder to make a more "fair" sequel to this one.

Comment: Oho! Thanks. @Bass I have a way of solving this that doesn't involve a pile of brute force.

Comment: Also, I did use an hour of my life to check if there were some clever choices of words or kids' names that would have made this solvable by hand. It turns out that there weren't.  Now that OP says that some of the given encryptions were even outright mistakes, I would like to have that hour back, please. (To be clear, it was the lack of quality checking that made me turn my +1 into a -1. This puzzle type does have some merits of its own, even if it turned out to be bit too tedious.)

Comment: @GarethMcCaughan Interesting! Maybe I have been too hasty in my judgement. I couldn't figure out a way to avoid branching after the first couple of steps.

Comment: @Bass I am sorry for the mistakes I made in this puzzle, I have never made these sorts of mistakes in the past, and will manually decrypt every solution in the future to make sure this doesn't happen again. I have an idea for a third puzzle, but that may very well be the last I do with this idea.

Comment: As you'll see now that I've posted my answer, it has a different drawback: I've essentially reduced the problem to linear algebra, so maybe it's now too maths-problem-y :-). But the "linearization" is sufficiently non-obvious that I think it's OK.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's begin by seeing what each chair has changed by over all the rounds it was involved in, by de-Vigenere-ing its final state using its initial state as key. We get, in order:

> SWLZDUD
>  UOQBYDT
>  QFOXUVR
>  HRBSHME
>  HILLARY
>  CZMSBR
>  JVROYVH
>  NZEGCZUCX

We can already see that

> the first chair to be removed was RICOTTA, and Hillary sat in it in the first round.

But let's take a different approach.

> If we "add" (the first six letters of) *all* the chairs' deltas, we get 1 of one child's name + 2 of another's + ... + 8 of another's. (Whichever child was eliminated first doesn't appear at all.) Each of those six letters gives us one linear relation, mod 26, between the numbers of times the children appear; e.g., if those numbers are $c_i,\dots,c_9$ for children A..I then the first letter is $c_1A+\cdots+c_9I$, the second is $c_1L+\cdots+c_9V$, etc. We also know that the sum of the numbers $c_1+\cdots+c_9$ is just $1+\cdots+8=36$. So we have seven linear relations between nine numbers. That leaves a relatively small space to search. I happen to have used Mathematica for this, but it could be done without: it's basically just linear algebra (with the slight complication that we're working to a non-prime modulus, but that doesn't hurt too much).

So:

> Add up all the deltas. Convert names and deltas to numbers. The equations described in the paragraph above look like this (in Mathematica's input language):
>  Reduce[{c1 + c2 + c3 + c4 + c5 + c6 + c7 + c8 + c9 == 36,
>  0 c1 + 1 c2 + 2 c3 + 3 c4 + 4 c5 + 5 c6 + 6 c7 + 7 c8 + 8 c9 == 14,
>  11 c1 + 4 c2 + 0 c3 + 4 c4 + 3 c5 + 11 c6 + 17 c7 + 8 c8 + 21 c9 == 7,
>  8 c1 + 13 c2 + 17 c3 + 13 c4 + 3 c5 + 14 c6 + 4 c7 + 11 c8 + 0 c9 == 8,
>  2 c1 + 1 c2 + 11 c3 + 8 c4 + 8 c5 + 5 c6 + 6 c7 + 11 c8 + 13 c9 == 12,
>  4 c1 + 4 c2 + 2 c3 + 18 c4 + 4 c5 + 11 c6 + 6 c7 + 0 c8 + 8 c9 == 3,
>  0 c1 + 13 c2 + 0 c3 + 4 c4 + 4 c5 + 14 c6 + 17 c7 + 17 c8 + 21 c9 == 6},
>  {c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6, c7, c8, c9}, Modulus -> 26]

which (more or less) just solves some linear equations, and returns this:

> c1 == C[1] && c2 == C[2] && c3 == 24 + 2 C[1] + 10 C[2] && 
>  c4 == 16 + 11 C[1] + 20 C[2] && c5 == 1 + 6 C[2] && 
>  c6 == 21 + 22 C[1] + 8 C[2] && c7 == 11 + 12 C[1] + 16 C[2] && 
>  c8 == 13 + 17 C[1] + 13 C[2] && c9 == 2 + 13 C[1] + 4 C[2]

meaning

> that we have (as we should expect since 9-7=2) a two-parameter family of solutions. But of course we have a further constraint, not so amenable to linear algebra: we know that the coefficients have to be 0,1,...,8 in some order. Well, we know that those parameters C[1] and C[2] are chosen from 0,1,...,8, so there are only 81 9-tuples to look at. That's not too much brute force, I think.
>  Select[Flatten[Table[Mod[{u, v, 24 + 2 u + 10 v, 16 + 11 u + 20 v, 1 + 6 v, 
>      21 + 22 u + 8 v, 11 + 12 u + 16 v, 13 + 17 u + 13 v, 
>      2 + 13 u + 4 v}, 26], {u, 0, 8}, {v, 0, 8}], 1], Max[#] == 8 &]

yielding this:

> {{4, 0, 6, 8, 1, 5, 7, 3, 2}}

In other words,

> A enciphered with her name 4 times, B 0 times, C 6 times, etc. So B was eliminated first, then E, then I, then H, then A, then F, then C, then G, and finally D who must be our winner.

It wouldn't be difficult to

> figure out who was in which chair when, but we don't actually have to.

Comment: Nice solution. Regarding the discussion at the comments to the question, I was trying to find a shortcut exactly because this method seemed to be *way* too much drudgework to be worth doing by hand.

Comment: Yeah, this is correct. I didn't intend for the solution to involve so much math, only a surface level amount. I intended it to be a series of equations, but I guess I messed up somewhere... Good work.

Comment: @Bass Fair enough. To me this seems like rather little drudgework, perhaps because I just take it for granted that linear algebra is a task for computers in the same way as multiplication is a task for calculators.